# How to launch an other screen than the main one after receiving a sharing intent in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, sharing

I've been trying to solve this but haven't succeeded yet.

I am planning a mobile application in flutter.
The main function of this app is to get a link from a different source/application and save it to my database. The problem is that when I receive a shared intent I want to open a new screen (not my main screen) where I'd complete the database process. Right now, it's not working as I want it to and it is redirecting to the main screen.

I am using the receive_sharing_intent library for getting the links from outsources.

I don't know what to do next since that feature (redirecting to a different screen) is vital for my application.

Comment: more info on this topic https://github.com/KasemJaffer/receive_sharing_intent/issues/62

Answer (score 0):

If you are using getx :

```
void onInit(){
ever(sharedText, (_){ 
  Get.toNamed('/otherScreen');
});
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).